# Stick a DIV at TOP and middle using CSS

Tags: html, css

So far I have this:

```
<style>
#success_notification {
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:30%;
text-align:center;
    font:20px Georgia;
    color:#5C5C5C;
    background:#F2FFED;
    padding:10px;
}

</style>

<div style="margin:0 auto;"><div id='success_notification'>TESTING.</div></div>
```

and the div stays on the left... still. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `text-align` does not center you div block it centers the text within your div block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't setting `left` or `right`, causing your absolutely-positioned element to default to a `left` of 0.  Try this:

```
#success_notification {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 35%;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    font: 20px Georgia;
    color: #5C5C5C;
    background: #F2FFED;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

Removed the position: absolute, added the margin: auto to style, added width 100% to outer div.  Works for me.

```
<style>
#success_notification {
top:0;
width:30%;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
    font:20px Georgia;
    color:#5C5C5C;
    background:#F2FFED;
    padding:10px;
}

</style>

<div style="width: 100%; margin:0 auto;"><div id='success_notification'>TESTING.</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#success_notification {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 50%;
    width:30%;
    text-align:center;
    font:20px Georgia;
    color:#5C5C5C;
    background:#F2FFED;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...or even:

float:left;

...or:

float:right

this works great in all browsers